# Represent a sum of IDs in a table in JSP, if the calculation is after the table tag

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

How can I represent a sum of IDs in a table in JSP, if the calculation is after the table tag?

I have a webproject with JSP servlets and Java. I have a JSP page like this in in myproject:

```
CountID: 
id | name |
```

**My JSP Code looks like this:**

```jsp
<table>
 <tr>
     <td>ConutID <%=lintcount%></td>
 </tr>
</table>
<table>
  for(int i=0; i<lobjList.size(); i++){
    Issue lobjIssue=(Issue)lobjList.get(i);
   if(lobjIssue.projectID = 1){
     lintcount++;
    }
 <tr>
         <td>ID</td>
         <td>name</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
        <td>lobjIssue.ID</td>
        <td>lobjIssue.Name</td>
 </tr>
</table>
}
```

My Question is:
 I want to write in my JSP after countID the sum of ID's. 
 But I count the sum of IDs in the for loop. And then I knew the result of ID's. 
 But I want to represent the sum of ids in the top of my HTML/JSP. 
 But in the top of my JSP I don't have the value.

Comment: Your Java code should be in scriptlets, I think.  You have `lintcount` in one, for example. However, you should consider using the JSTL, with the `<c:forEach>` tag.  Why is the *sum of IDs* meaningful?  Isn't that like adding up social security numbers?

Comment: You need `==`, not `=` in your `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just put lobjList.size()

your code should give same value for lintcount after loop (if you don't have syntax errors)

```
<td>ConutID <%=lobjList.size()%></td>
```

otherwise loop to count above the first table

```
for(Issue lobjIssue: lobjList){
   if(lobjIssue.projectID == 1){
     lintcount++;
    }

<table>
 <tr>
     <td>ConutID <%=lintcount%></td>
 </tr>
</table>
<table>
  for(int i=0; i<lobjList.size(); i++){
    Issue lobjIssue=(Issue)lobjList.get(i);

 <tr>
         <td>ID</td>
         <td>name</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
        <td>lobjIssue.ID</td>
        <td>lobjIssue.Name</td>
 </tr>
</table>
}
```

Comment: Sorry i modify my post, the lintCount++ have to count up if the lobjIssue.projectID = 1. So the lobjList.size() has another value then lintcount

Answer (score 0):

Don't embed Java in JSPs; it does not work out well.  Instead, use JSTL tags.  Also, adding up id values does not seem useful; I assume you mean a count.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>

<jsp:useBean id="issues" scope="request">
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">
                ${fn:length(issues)} issues
            </th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <c:forEach items="${issues}" var="issue">
            <tr>
                <td>${issue.id}</td>
                <td>${issue.name}</td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I assume the instance variable names are the standard `id` and `name`.  I didn't notice the importance of project id 1 to you; I think you should do that processing on the Java side.  Have an `Issues` object that contains a `List<Issue>` object and has a method `getMasterProjectCount()`  Change the above JSTL JSP accordingly.